# R Connecting charts

Tags: r, plot

I have  code that plot histograms.

```
library(ggplot2)

sample.range <- 50:150
mean <- 100
sd <- 15
set.seed(1)
n.samples <- c(1000, 10000)
my.df <- do.call(
           rbind, 
           lapply(
             n.samples, 
             function(x) data.frame(
                           "SampleSize" = x, 
                           "control" = rnorm(x, mean, sd)
                         )
           )
         )

ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(data = my.df, aes(x = control)) + 
  facet_wrap(.~SampleSize, scales = "free_y")
```

I want to get graphs exactly like in the attached picture.  The green bar is mean.
[[image: plot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kib87.png)]

Unfortunately, these are my first attempts to draw such complicated graphs, so please help me

Comment: What do you mean by `"The green bar is medium"`, maybe mean? meadian?

Comment: Sorry yes its mean

Comment: An idea could be to add a constant value to each dark grey sample and make one plot with the light and dark grey values which will connect and differ by the constant value

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```r
ggplot(data = within(my.df, SampleSize <- paste(SampleSize, 'Samples'))) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = control, fill = factor(SampleSize)),
                 color = 'gray70') + 
  geom_vline(data = . %>% group_by(SampleSize) %>% 
                    summarize(mean = mean(control)), size = 5,
             aes(xintercept = mean, color = factor(SampleSize))) +
  facet_wrap(.~SampleSize, scales = "free_y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#abb0b2", "#596160")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00862a", "#00862a")) +
  guides(fill = guide_none(), color = guide_none()) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16, face = 'bold'))
```

[image]